# PHP How to get the full longitude and the latitude using google API

Tags: php, geolocation, google-api

Please I have made this code to get the longitude and the latitude :

```
$addresss = "France+mande-lieu-la-napol";
$region   = "Alpes-Maritimes";
$urll      = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$addresss&sensor=false&region=$region";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urll);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);

var_dump ($response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat );

var_dump ( $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng );
```

This code gives me as result :

```
float(43.546232) float(6.938309)
```

But in real it must give me

```
float(43.546232) float(6.938309000000004)
```

Please what should I do to get the full longitude ?

Comment: why?  what is wrong with the current values it returns?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)` so that the lat and long will be returned as strings instead of floats.